# Angular 7: adding local module with npm link

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I've created a package with a module outside of folder with an appication that should contain the module to test it. Then I've added package with `npm link @scope/module-name`. After that I've added paths to root `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@scope/module-name": [
        "node_modules/@scope/module-name"
      ],
      "@scope/module-name/*": [
        "node_modules/@scope/module-name/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I've also added package to `include` in `tsconfig.app.json`

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "../node_modules/@scope/**/*.ts",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

And yes, I've added `"preserveSymlinks": true` in `angular.json` as it's said in similar questions on SO.

In `app.module.ts` I'm doing

```
import { DispRegistryModule } from "@scope/module-name/public_api.d.ts";
```

But still I'm gettig an error

> ERROR in ./node_modules/@scope/module-name/public_api.d.ts Module
>   build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
>   Error:
>   D:\internal\test-app\node_modules@scope\module-name\public_api.d.ts
>   is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in
>   your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

How can I fix the error?